# troubles with powershell where clause

Tags: powershell, escaping

i am trying to parse a website for specific data.

```
$strings = $body.split(";")
$strings2 = $strings.Where({$_ -like ("*recordData[`"key`"]*")})
```

i figured out that the square brackets are to blame, i use

```
$strings2 = $strings.Where({$_ -like ("*recordData*")})
```

and it works fine, albeit returning way more results then i need.
is there a way i can just search for "recordData[key]"

$body is just the entirety of a returned webpage

thanks.

EDIT:
as requested the input data is like this

```
rs.currentColumn = 0;
recordData["dataGridExtraRow"] = 0;
recordData["rownum"] = "0";

recordData["key"] = '3354087';

recordData["factory"] = "cr";
```

in the end i need the 3354087 number, but just picking out the lines i needed was the issue, after that i can pick apart the string fine.

however, i ended up using the .contains, thanks for the suggestion.
sort of facepalmed after i saw it though.

Comment: You could use the -match operator with appropriate regex (forgive me for my lack of regex knowledge)

Comment: This would work better if you showed some sample data and expected result. Also if this is from a website are you using `Invoke-Webrequest`?

Comment: yeah, used Invoke-Webrequest
i added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the like operator then you are going to be having an issue with the open square bracket which is a wildcard character in PowerShell. See [About_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1)

> ```
> ...
> [] - Matches range of characters
> ...
> ```

A use case would be something like this which would return true.

```
"recordFata" -like "record[DF]ata"
```

So if you are going to be using `-like` you need to escape the brackets using backticks in a single quoted sting. You can avoid that by using other methods that function in the same way you intended.

---

Other options

### String .Contains() Method

```
"sdfafdrecordData[key]asdfasdfas".Contains("recordData[key]")
```

Fairly basic and no need to worry about special characters for the most part.

### Regex

```
"sdfafdrecordData[key]asdfasdfas" -match "recordData\[key]"
```

Note that the square braces are also regex metacharacters that need to be escaped as well.

Comment: Doubling `[` is not correct way you escape `[` in PowerShell wildcard: `"sdfafdrecordData[notkey]asdfasdfas"-like "*recordData[[key]*"`

Comment: thanks for the contains method, that did the trick.
sort of facepalmed when i saw it, i knew about it and didn't think to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes and escaping with backticks.

You can also simplify using PowerShell syntax:

`` $strings = $body -split ';' -like '*recordData`[key`]*' ``